# Where are image paths to product category images stored in WordPress database

Tags: database, sql

I am using WooCommerce I purposely deleted all my unattached image in media without realizing it was going to delete all product categories images

Luckily I have a back up database and all the images

But I cant seem to find where the path to the product categories images are being stored in the database

I looked all over

```
wp_termmeta
wp_terms
wp_term_relationships
wp_term_taxonomy
```

And it doesn't seem to be there can anyone guid me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Category images are stored as attachments, which is a post type.  You'll find them in wp_posts with a post_type "attachment".  The guid field contains the location of the image.